# How to check which JmsOutboundGateway was used by Messaging Gateway ( two JmsOutboundGateway attached to same input channel) - Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, ibm-mq

I have problem with Spring Integration - MessagingGateway. I created gateway interface and attached to it's requestChannel two ServiceActivators.

Everything works fine but I would like to monitor which ServiceActivator(JmsOutboundGateway) is used while I will trigger gateway method ( sendMsg()) - monitoring where messages are actually sent (which JmsOutboundGateway was used) - I assume the mq connection may be closed randomly for the first or second JmsOutboundGateway.

Is there any chance to somehow monitor it ?

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "LocalGateway")
public interface LocalGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
    ListenableFuture<Message<String>> sendMsg(Message<String> request);

}
```

---

```
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
    public JmsOutboundGateway firstGateway(){
    // some code
}

@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
    public JmsOutboundGateway secondGateway(){
    // some code
}
```

---

```
// use of  gateway  
    public sendMessage(){

    ListenableFuture<Message<String>> result localGateway.sendMsg("Message");

    result.addCallback(new CustomCallback());

    // some code
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to tell which IBM MQ queue has been used when a message is sent?

Comment: rather I would like to know which mq server and queue Manager  was used.  Both  ServiceActivator use same queue but on different mq server with different names of queueManager.

Comment: OK understand - so spotting the SVRCONN channel starting up might be one way, or monitoring both queues (one on each queue manager) would be another way. Do you want a way to look after the fact, or while it's happening. I think with these answers I should be able to write up some sort of answer.

Comment: there is one problem - I need to connect this data with request/flow that used spring gateway - so rather I'm looking for solution directly in spring integration framework.  
 I'm checking attaching ChannelInterceptor in  MessageChannel that i use with overriding afterSendCompletion or Send but its not working fine.

Comment: Was that an answer to my previous comment? I don't speak "spring" I only speak MQ. I guess that's why none of that made any sense to me. I see you have an answer in spring terminology below, so perhaps you don't need any help with MQ monitoring concepts. If you do, see my previous comment for questions, and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks for help :) Mq monitoring would be the last hope - but due to performance it would be best to solve it directly in Java app - within spring framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand that default channel is a `DirectChannel` which comes with a round-robin handling strategy for its subscribers. So, the first message will go to first subscriber, the second to second. And so on until all subscribers are iterated, then we come back to first one for the next sent messages.

Now, if that is OK with you, there is a way to attache a Message History into messages where you can track a journey for the message.

Your `@ServiceActivator` might be marked with a `@EndpointId` if you find the long name generated from the method name as not convenient.

See more info in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/message-history.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/configuration/annotations.html

Comment: Thanks for explanation. :)  I'm afraid that Message History may decrease app performance - JmsOutboundGateway  (MQ) will be heavy loaded.   

  It works very good but maybe there is some other way to solve it?

Comment: Interface for gateway - ServiceActivator returns ListenableFuture<Message<String>>.
When this method is called,  I add to  ListenableFuture object a callback object.

For me, the most important thing is that when sending or receiving messages through the gateway fails, I should extract information about which ServiceActivator was used in the onError method of the callback object.

Maybe it is possible to provide such information in a throwable object?

Comment: Or adding custom header to message before sending it ? but I don`t know how to do it.

Comment: In the case of `ListenableFuture` return of the gateway method you definitely can track the failure via exception in that `onFailure()` callback. That one though is deprecated in Spring Framework `6.0` in favor of `CompletableFuture` from Java.

Comment: I checked error flow and I found bean name only in one place -> Throwable object (AggregateMessageDeliveryException) -> cause (Messaging Exception) ->  cause (MessagingHandlingException) ->  cause (MessagingHandlingException) ->  detailMessage     =  failed to handle a message in the [bean 'jmsOutboundGatewaySecondGateway'; defined in: 'class path resource

Comment: so if something will fail while processing in jmsOutboundGateway( as Service Activator) I can always expect same type of exception ( message with bean name ) ?

Comment: and in case positive flow - in JmsOutboundGateway I'm adding HeaderMapper  which adds custom header to check which bean was used.

Comment: OK. You can go that direction, indeed. However, if you already add some headers manually, there is no too much difference with Message History I suggested in my answer. You can configure it just for a limited set of components to track.

Comment: When the flow with gateway end in onFailure - all headers added in DefaultJmsHeaderMapper are missing. Is there any possibility to add custom headers and then pick them in callback. OnFailure ?

Comment: * just somehow bypass custom headers in JmsOutboundGateway  - and pick then up in onFailure function.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper`. You can track headers in the failure only if you set them before sending downstream. The `onFailure` callback should give an access to the `MessagingException` where we have a `failedMessage` property which should have the headers you are looking for.

Comment: I use retries for those gateways and due to round robin mechanism I would like to know which bean was used aat last execution before flow fails - throws exception. I can try to search information from exception - getMessege() but its not optimal. Is it true that @EnableHistory can significantly reduce gateway performance?

Comment: Well, most of the handlers throw an exception like this: `throw new MessageHandlingException(requestMessage, "failed to handle a message in the [" + this + ']', e);`. So, that one would indeed has some info where it exactly failed. The better header is indeed Message History. We have an issue to tackle it performance though: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/7925

Comment: Another way to optimize performance is to have a `messageBuilderFactory` bean of `MutableMessageBuilderFactory` instance. But that may lead to some unexpected behavior somewhere since the same message instance is going to be used everywhere.